# Need help writing a function which returns a dictionary with the keys as recursive digit sums

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, recursion

So I have written a function which calculates the sum of the digits when a number is input to the function. Now I am trying to write another function which would return a dictionary with the values from my digitsum function as the keys and the values would be how many times the count of that specific digitsum has occurred. Any ideas on how to go about writing the second function?

```
def digitsum(x):
    if x < 10:
        return x
    else:
        return (x%10) + digitsum(x//10)

def digitsumdictionary(lnum=0, hnum=100):
    L =[digitsum(num) for num in range(100)]
    counter = Counter(L).items()
    return counter
```

Comment: _"would be how many times the count of that specific digitsum has occurred"_ has occurred in what?

Comment: So if the function were to be run multiple times. How many time would the digitsum 22 occurr. Does that kind of help explain it a little better?

Comment: Use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter): `Counter(map(digitsum, numbers))`

Comment: I recommend you change the `if x == 0: return 0 elif x != 0: ...` to `if x < 10: return x else: ...`

Comment: Thanks, Patrick and user633183! I seem to be on the right track now however it still seems to not be working properly

Answer (score 0):

Digitsum function is called depending on the length of the number.

You can simply find it by using `len(list(str(num)))`. But if you want to count as the function calls itself, Then try this,

```
def digitsum(x, count=1): 
    if x < 10:
        return { x : count }
    else:
        return {(x%10) + int(list(digitsum(x//10 , count+1).keys())[0]) : int(list(digitsum(x//10 , count+1).values())[0])}
```

Setting the count to 1 or 0 initially, includes or excludes the first call respectively.

The below code returns a list of dictionaries of the desired output.

```
[digitsum(i) for i in range(10)]
```